# WPF - UserControl inheritance

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have problem with control inheritance in WPF. I created a  UserControl named BaseUserControl. I want for this control to be a base control for other WPF userControls. So I wrote another UserControl called FirstComponent. In next step I changed this code

```
FirstComponent : UserControl
```

to this

```
FirstComponent : BaseControl
```

However during compilation I get this error

```
Partial declarations of 'controlinheritance.componenets.FirstComponent' must not specify different base classes
```

What should I do to enable FirstComponent to derive from BaseControl?

EDIT
Thanks to abhishek answer I managed to inherit controls . Howerver I have another question. In base class I specified a property public Grid _MainGrid { get; set; }. Now I want in my derived class create an instance of this grid. So I used this code                                                                           
    
    

Howerver I get an error  Property '_MainGrid' does not have a value. Line 8 Position 36.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see my complete article on it?

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article832-define-base-class-for-window--usercontrol-.aspx

I hope that would help you in this.

> If you try to execute the project, it would definitely throw error to
>   you. This is because, every WPF window is created from the baseWindow
>   layout rather than the current Window layout. In other words, if you
>   see the XAML, you will see the root tag is Window, which is a class
>   just parent of the current window.
>
> Thus to ensure everything works perfectly, we need to change the Root
>   Element.
>
> So it would look like :
>
> ```
> <local:BaseWindow Class="BaseWindowSample.Window1" 
>                   Name="winImp" 
>                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
>                   x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BaseWindowSample" 
>                   Title="Window1">
> ...
> </local:BaseWindow>
> ```
>
> If you see this minutely, you can see I have added one namespace to my
>   project and named it as local. So BaseWindow should come from
>   BaseWindow and thus it goes like local:BaseWindow

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot. Could You look at my edigted message

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason for the initial error was because the class was actually a partial class that was listing a particular base inheritance somewhere else in addition to the location where you changed your base class.

As for your property 'inheritance', I suggest trying

```
public Grid MainGrid 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      return base.MainGrid; 
   } 

   set 
   { 
      base.MainGrid = value; 
   } 
}
```

However I should note that this will not give you a link to any existing instance(s) of your base class. If you want there to be a guaranteed link in your derived class to the lone instance of that Grid, then you will have to make the base class property a static.
In which case, your code will look like this...

```
public Grid MainGrid
{
    get
    {
        return BaseControl.MainGrid;
    }

    set
    {
        BaseControl.MainGrid = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a Different base class for a Usercontrol in the XAML.cs file

```
 FirstComponent : BaseControl
```

You should also change this in the XAML

```
 <Base:BaseControl x:Class="FirstComponent"
             xmlns:Base="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Base"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>


    </Grid>
</Base:BaseControl>
```