# Derive cs class from a wpf-class with xaml which is in another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a base class like that in the project `A`

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für Layer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Layer
    {
        public Layer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

with this xaml (in my project it has a complex tooltip, but for simplicity I changed it to a TextBlock)

```
<Canvas x:Class="WpfApplication1.Layer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Canvas.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="ToolTip"/>
    </Canvas.ToolTip>
</Canvas>
```

For testing purpose I want to derive from that in my TestAssembly

```
using WpfApplication1;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class TestingLayer : Layer
    {
    }
}
```

But when I start I get the the

```
The component `TestingLayer` does not have a resource identified by the URI `/WpfApplication1;component/layer.xaml`
```

I already googled and found some threads related to that problem, but with some differences:

- [The component does not have a resource identified by the uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646331/the-component-does-not-have-a-resource-identified-by-the-uri)

This one suggests to make a wrapper around `TestingLayer` but unfortunately this doesn't work for me because I want to get access to some protected funtions (especially to `OnRender` whose access I can't modify). Furthermore the OP wants a derived control with xaml, and this is a big difference to my needs, because my derived class has no xaml. This difference also applies to these threads

- [Best practice to resolve the URI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067595/best-practice-to-resolve-the-uri-error)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957231

Since the derivation works when I create `TestingLayer` in my project `A` I think there is just a problem in the URI. But I don't know how to solve it.

To sum it up: **How to derive a c# class with only a cs file from a control (with xaml) from another assembly?**

Comment: Controls are suitable for aggregation, not for inheritance. If you mean unit testing, then you shouldn't do this. Actually, I can't imagine unit test for `OnRender` (which either renders content correctly, or incorrectly).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To help your imagination about a unit test for `OnRender` look at this post of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622996/unit-testing-custom-onrender-method?lq=1

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like over-using of unit testing, and WPF infrastructure just confirms this.

Comment: @Dennis: is your last comment about this question or about the thread I linked? But nevertheless, nor does it answer my question neither does it contribute the my question (which was how to derive from a control in another assembly). This question isn't about the right usage of unit-testing.

Comment: I think this has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503232/wpf-can-i-inherit-a-usercontrol-but-provide-no-xaml

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982191/wpf-usercontrol-inheritance?rq=1 where the accepted answer might be helpful to you.

Comment: @o_weisman: there is the same difference as the one I pointed out in my question: **My derived control (`TestingLayer`) has no xaml**.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the last suggestion I gave you has a xaml file only for the base class, but I could be wrong

Comment: @o_weisman: the xaml quoted in the answer (which begins with `<local:BaseWindow Class="BaseWindowSample.Window1" `) is the xaml of the `Window1` which derives from `BaseWindow`. That means the derived control has its own xaml. This is also very clear from the linked article where you can read `Window1 : BaseWindow` and in the constructor of `Window1` is `InitializeComponent();` which tells me, that `Window1` has xaml.